# How to fix the font sizes of DB browser for sqlite, which got tiny due to remote Windows server update?

Tags: windows, fonts, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016, sqlite

[image]

Recently after an update in Windows server 2016 OS (64-bit), few apps font size went too tiny to be able to read. Currently my interest is for "DB browser for sqlite". Tried to fix it with below approaches:

- Control Panel > Display Settings > Custom scaling
- BTW, Display settings customization isn't allowed as this OS is hosted on a remote session in AWS
- Changing sqlite DB browser own font sizes; Though I was not able to read them at first, I managed from some screenshots available in other forums
- Reinstalling the DB browser itself

None of these worked. How to make them readable like before?

Comment: Use another SQLite management tool?  There are many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By trial and error method, I was able to solve the issue by clicking "Restore Defaults" at the bottom left!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, Edit -> Preferences -> Restore defaults did not work. But in Edit -> Preferences -> General tab, there was a tiny Font option which had somehow got set to 4. Changed it to 9, and that restored SQLite UI to a readable font size!

[image: Screenshot Preferences General tab font size]